# gdb - x86_64 assembly - viewing stack

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, stack-memory

I debug the assembly code of the following simple program:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

I set the breakpoint on the return statement. gdb shows the following assembly code (intel syntax):

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x00005555555545fa <+0>: push   rbp
   0x00005555555545fb <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00005555555545fe <+4>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5
=> 0x0000555555554605 <+11>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555460a <+16>:    pop    rbp
   0x000055555555460b <+17>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Here is the info about rsp register:

```
(gdb) info reg rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdcb0   0x7fffffffdcb0
```

The value of the x variable should be placed on the stack, how to print the stack ? I try the following command but without success:

```
(gdb) x/10x $rsp
0x7fffffffdcb0: 0x55554610  0x00005555  0xf7a03c87  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdcc0: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0xffffdd98  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdcd0: 0x00008000  0x00000001
```

Moreover I don't understand why the difference between the above addresses is equal 16.

Comment: Note that the assembly code stores 5 to `rbp - 4`. You should be inspecting `$rbp - 4` or `$rsp - 4` (since the mov made both of them equal) When in doubt, ask GDB with `print &x`.

Comment: As for your other question, `x/10x` prints memory in chunks of 4-bytes. It printed 4 chunks on one line, which is 16 bytes. So the next line starts 16 bytes later.

Comment: Technically `x/10x` uses whatever the last size was but in this case yeah, it's 4 bytes.

Comment: How to print one chunk per line ?

Comment: I don't see a way to specify items per line. Also, at least my version of gdb apparently ignores `set width`. So that seems to leave only scripting if you really need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The value of the x variable should be placed on the stack, how to print the stack ?

What you're seeing is something called a [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) - any function is allowed to use some stack space *below* the stack pointer. It's an optimization at ABI level - the stack pointer only needs moved when calling another function or exceeding the red zone (128 bytes on SysV ABI).

Notice that the value is stored 4 bytes *below* the frame pointer `rbp` (which here is equal to the stack pointer `rsp`).

```
                            mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5
```

So try printing the stack starting from `$rsp - 4` or less.

```
x/10wx $rsp-4
```

Or compile with `-mno-red-zone` (but note that on SysV ABI stack pointer is aligned on 16 bytes so your value will probably be at `$rsp + 12`).

> Moreover I don't understand why the difference between the above addresses is equal 16

The memory dump contains 16 bytes per line (see 4 values of 4 bytes each). So next line starts 16 bytes later (or 0x10). with `x/10x` you requested to print 10 hex values (by default dwords), so you get 40 bytes of memory printed.

You can print a single dword value with `x/wx $rsp-4`.

For more details refer to [GDB docs - Memory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html).